# Can I add onClick() event on custom link menu on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress, when using a theme, how can I prevent a click event from happening on a custom link. I am thinking of adding the following:

```
onClick="return false"
```

I am trying to prevent the page from scrolling down unexpectedly, when clicked.

Answer (score 3):

do you have access to the theme edition? If so, you can try to use something like the code below, it's

add in footer.php

if you do not have access, but the theme has some custom field.

```
<script>
        //JQUERY
        (function ($) {
            $('a[href=#]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        })(jQuery)

        //JS PURE
        document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]').forEach(function(ele, i){
            ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Do the following, create a custom html widget and add the code in it.

Comment: JQUERY

`<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[href=#]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            })

        })
    })(jQuery);
</script>`



PURE JS

`<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {        
        document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]').forEach(function(ele, i){
            ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        })
    })
</script>`